# Python: Recognize if image contains graphic/text or a picture

Tags: python, image, image-recognition

I want to write a script, that converts unknown images (jpg, png, gif, bmp, tiff, etc.) to a specific resolution and format as well as generating a thumbnail.

the problem is that the compression level, that is totally fine for pictures produces crap for exports of Presentations for example; So I want to differ the conversion settings based on the contents of the image.

Does anyone have experience in doing that kind of stuff in python (or shell scripts whose output is easily pasreable)?

my ideas are:

- increase contrast and check histogramm if there are only single spikes left
- doing a high pass filtering of the image and check what?
- doing face recognition of known letters

the goal is that the recognition should be quite fast (approx. 10 images/second) and quite easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty trivial machine learning problem, I would research the MNIST dataset problems that teach you how to recognize handwritten characters, this process should be very similar. Check out this tutorial and see if you can modify it to recognize graphics vs pictures. If your error rate ends up too high you'll have to try more advanced machine learning techniques.

http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/mnist.html